# iOS Map pin bubble out of screen

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary

When i click on a pin on the map and if the pin is on the borders of the iPhone screen, the bubble comes off the screen, i.e. Half ourside of the viewport and half inside the viewport.
Is there is any property etc which will show the bubble automatically centered on the screen.!
Check this image below to know more about what i mean
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSWmZ.png

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to make it so that everytime an annotation is selected, you change the map's center coordinate to the coordinate of your annotation? Instead of calculating the pop up view's dimensions, just do it every time instead. Here's the code to do this. Put this into your delegate for MKMapView

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *) theMapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annoView{

[theMapView setCenterCoordinate:annoView.annotation.coordinate animated:YES];


}
```

Once you've done this, you should be all set.

Also, it's curious to note, that when I tried implementing a mapview, and I added annotations, whenever I selected them, the map automatically moved so as to display the whole calloutView. I wonder why yours isn't doing that. Anyway, if my answer helped, please accept it as your answer. Thnx

Comment: Thanx @Fear, will try and let you know !

Answer (score 1):

Mapkit does a great job of positioning the map when annotations are selected but it can't magically account for other UI elements you've placed in the scene that are obscuring things.

You need to either resize your mapview when your search box is down so it is not obscuring it or you need to add logic to reposition the map if a annotation is selected which is near the top of the view when the search box is visible.

Comment: If you check the iPhone's google map and see how it works, it works very well ... It does push the annotation within the screen area if it is outside the screen. Dont know if they recalculate and set the position though !

Comment: @Nick, did you even look at his screen shot? His issue has nothing to do with the top of the screet, the problem is the sides.

@Zuzar, Why don't you make it so that everytime an annotation is selected, you change the map's center coordinate to the coordinate of your annotation? Instead of calculating the pop up view's dimensions, just do it every time instead. Would probably save a lot of headache.

Comment: @Fear: Nicks comment was right, coz the screen shot i had put earlier was different, to make more sense after he commented, i had added one more screenshot, but this site didn't allow me to put two url as i dont have permissions yet, so had to remove the older one. But yes, its a good idea to change the maps center coordinates with my annotations coordinates. Will try this option out !

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. @Nick, please accept my apologies. I was out of line.

Comment: @Fear, any idea how to get the annotations positions value?

Comment: yea, whatever your annotation object is, it has a property called coordinate. So it'll just be myAnnotation.coordinate.latitude and myAnnotation.coordinate.longitude

Comment: Yeah that's the problem with using external image services :). Fear's answer seems right on. Remember you can also use the subtitle to break up your annotation text if you can logically. Or, use a custom annotation. Centering seems like a good bet regardless. Sorry for any confusion on my end earlier as well.